# jQuery, reuse method for many divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

I have a CoffeeScript code that looks like this:

```
 if $('#user_address_attributes_country').val() == ""
    $('#user_address_attributes_country').val("PL")
```

Now I want to do the same thing for a few divs but without repetitions.
How can it be done by jQuery?

Comment: share some more info like what are you doing before if condition, div relations etc. Share html code.

Comment: The Condition will be:
if div value is == "" then set it to "PL"
But I want to do this on three dvis. I tried to use each jQuery method but I was doing something wrong.

Comment: Thats what I wanted to ask, on which event you are doing this... share what have you tried and your html code

Comment: Div's cannot share the same ID so give them all a common class such as `class="country-class"` then you can get them all and use `each` like this `$('.country-class').each(function(){if($(this).val() == "") $(this).val('PL')});`

Comment: But this divs are in different pages so this doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

The reason you can't apply it multiple times is because your trying to apply it to an element which has an `id`. They are unique. Use `classes` and do this instead:

```
if ($('.user_address_attributes_country').val("")) {
    $('.user_address_attributes_country').val("PL");
}
```

Simple demo: 

## JsFiddle